# cannot set Spring security for all url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I created  a spring mvc application with spring security. I tried to set authentication for all url with spring security.

### Springsecurity.xml

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" >
            <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />    
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

When I giving intercept-url to `/**` the page doesnot loading. It makes a timeout.
But when giving intercept-url to `/admin` it works perfectly. Why this happens?

Comment: Have you tried `intercept-url pattern="/*"`?

Comment: yes, I tried "/*". But it is also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intercept pattern for all request is OK, but you need to include an exception for your login page, try adding

```
  <http security="none" pattern="/login"/>
```

**UPDATE** with respect to the comment

The approach above completely switches off Spring security for the given URL. As you're using CSFR, it means that spring security filter should attend to this URL as well, but not for the sake of the authentication, rather for the sake of including the unpredictable token that can secure from session fixation attacks. In any case, here's a way to process the URL with spring security, without prompting for authentication. Instead of using the above, use the following

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()"/>
```

inside the

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        ...
```

Comment: where can i add this Line? Before <http auto-config ?

Comment: yeps, before http auto-config

Comment: After adding this line it give the error on ftl. "Expression _csrf is undefined " ${_csrf.parameterName}

Comment: I tried it. But it gives the execption "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'"

Comment: 'k updated again, switched to isAnonymous, let me know

Comment: could you please take a look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926975/spring-mvc-login-with-spring-security-behave-differently